# calculate one value greater than another by 300%

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to write a calculation for a program code but cannot figure out how the math would work. My goal is to have a calculation that would read something like value A is greater than value b by 300% or more.

I know this is a mathematics forum but if it helps the code is in python and would be an if statement like:

```
if value a is greater than value b by 300% or more then violation, else not a violation.
```

Comment: sorry about my bad explanation, im having trouble putting it into words how i need it and am trying to avoid programming language specific stuff, been a while since i had a math class

Comment: $300\%$ of $b$? So for example, if $b=3$, do you want $a$ at most  $3+9=12$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if b*3<a then
   ...
else
   ...
```

This will check if a is 3 times larger than b since $a*300\% = a*3$.

Comment: This is checking if $b$ is $300\%$ of $a$, not whether it is $300\%$ *more* than $a$.   Sometimes people are not careful about the wording and what you do may be what OP intended.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When we say a percentage like 300% what we really mean is 3*(100%). You would just take the value of $b$ (which is 100%) and multiply it by 3 and then add that to $b$. In Python this would look something like this:

```
if a >= 3*b+b:
    print "Violation"
else:
    print "Not a violation"
```

Comment: wouldnt that add up to 400% though, essentially a> 300% + 100%?

Comment: Yes, 400% of $b$ is 300% more than $b$. In other words if a store has a 30% off sale, you pay $price-.3*price$, and not $.3*price$.

Comment: ok, my fault there then, i explained it incorrectly for what i needed, but your answer was helpful none the less. thanks.